# How to save state with Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have switcher function which I created in order to change state of my icon according to information taken from firebase. So, when
"isFavSalon" in switcher is true the icon should be filled else it should be not filled. isFavSalon must be getting from firebase.

The switcher:

```
initState() {
isFavSalonBlock = widget.isFavSalon;
print(isFavSalonBlock);
super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
void switcherIsFavSalon() async {
  var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  var docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('customers')
      .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
      .collection('favSalons');

  if (isFavSalonBlock == false) {
    setState(() {
      favIconBlock = 'assets/icons/heart_filled.png';
      isFavSalonBlock = true;
      docRef.add({
        "salonName": widget.salonName,
        "workTime": widget.workTime,
        "location": widget.location,
        "rating": widget.rating,
        "isFavSalon": isFavSalonBlock,
      });
    });
  } else {
    setState(() {
      favIconBlock = 'assets/icons/heart_border.png';
      isFavSalonBlock = false;
      docRef.get().then((value) {
        value.docs.forEach((element) async {
          if (element.data()['salonName'] == widget.salonName)
            await docRef.doc(element.id).delete();
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

favIcon in this switcher pass to the icon's image path.
Also, I have function which gets information from firebase and stores it in my Block.

The function:

```
getFavSalons(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
return snapshot.data.docs
    .map((doc) => SalonBlock(
          salonName: doc.data()["salonName"],
          location: doc.data()["location"],
          workTime: doc.data()["workTime"],
          rating: doc.data()["rating"],
        ))
    .toList();
}
```

But when I restart my app and switch between pages state of icons doesn't change according to information stored in firebase.
However when I press on the icon information is sending to firebase.
So how can I save the state in my app?

Comment: You first need to check if you are receiving the data.

Comment: data is saved in firebase but I can't receive it

Comment: You need to fix that first then, one problem at a time.

Comment: can you check edit? i tried this way but unfortunately i can't recieve the data

Comment: We can't test your connection and reception of data from your Firestore/Firebase account. It's not something we can replicate. You need to check where the data is failing. If any data at all is arriving, and if so, what is missing.

Comment: For questions or concerns pertaining to Firebase products and services, I would like to direct you to the [Firebase Support page](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact?authuser=0). As they would be better suited in providing answers to your Firebase inquiries.